# R sf package - link to GDAL

Tags: gdal, r, sf

Is it possible to ask R {sf} package to use a GDAL installation I prefer?

So far I found how to check external software it uses:

```
library(sf)
sf_extSoftVersion()

#          GEOS           GDAL         proj.4 GDAL_with_GEOS 
#       "3.6.1"        "2.2.3"        "4.9.3"         "true"
```

I am hoping I can choose a path to my existing GDAL installation like {gdalUtils} package does:

```
library(gdalUtils)
# To change the path to GDAL 
gdal_setInstallation(search_path = "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.4\\bin", rescan = TRUE,
                     ignore.full_scan = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)

# To check the result
getOption("gdalUtils_gdalPath")[[1]]$path
#       [1] "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/bin/"
getOption("gdalUtils_gdalPath")[[1]]$version
#       version 
#       "2.4.0"
```

If this is possible, {sf} (and {stars}) package can use GDAL 2.4.0 under the hood of QGIS 3.4.

---

[Background]

In my previous question [R stars package and set dimensions to a NetCDF file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314912/r-stars-package-and-set-dimensions-to-a-netcdf-file) I leaned my issue was not reproducible in other environment. Now trying to see if change of environment can improve the situation. Upgrading GDAL version is the first step.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this? Running into compatibility issues with layers

Comment: @Simbamangu no...unfortunately.

Comment: You'll have to compile sf yourself, and disable the tools/ rwinlib process. It's challenging and probably needs you to compile GDAL as well

Comment: Thanks @mdsumner umm...it is definitely beyond my skill......(´・＿・`)